# How to send data from google appscript to an html page

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, return-value

I have a google app script that has multiple features. I want to display some of the data on sidebar **html page**. Here is what I have tested.

```
function getColumnData(sheetName){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var rangeData = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var firstRow = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var firstRowMapped = firstRow.reduce(function(a, b) {return a.concat(b)}); // to convert 2d to 1d
    Logger.log(firstRowMapped);
    return firstRowMapped;
} // returns the first Row t html form for population
```

and on the html side I want to get whatever this function is returning.

```
function getRow() {
        var sheetName = document.getElementById("sheetname").value.toString();
        var firstRow = getColumnData(sheetName);
        var checkBox = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
        var firstRow = google.script.run.getColumnData(sheetName)
        for (var columns in firstRow){
        checkBox.innerHTML += `<label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="${firstRow[columns]}"/>
        <span>${firstRow[columns]}</span>
      </label><br>`
      }
      }
```

This should work according to my understanding. But sadly it isn't getting any data.
Any Ideas to why?

Comment: Can you show your function that creates the sidebar?

Comment: @ziganotschka 
```javascript 
function onOpen() {
  var form = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("form");
  var html = form.evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

Comment: From your code it is not clear what you are are trying to do - are you retrieving column data and checkboxes from a Google Spreadsheet or from a HTML website? Please provide your full code, including your html code

Comment: @ziganotschka i am trying to get data from google sheets to populate a google sidebar html. Anyway, I fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Glad you found the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me. You will have to pass a function to receive the data into `withSuccessHandler()`

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler("a function that will receive the data")."the function that gets the data"
// in my case
      function getRow() {
        var sheetName = document.getElementById("sheetname").value.toString();

        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(populateChecks)
          .getColumnData(sheetName);
      }
      function populateChecks(firstRow) {
        var checkBox = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
        for (var columns in firstRow) {
          checkBox.innerHTML += `<label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="${firstRow[columns]}"/>
        <span>${firstRow[columns]}</span>
      </label><br>`;
        }
      }
```